# DecimalFormat formatting from one decimal double to two decimals

Tags: java, formatting, format, double

I am trying to figure out DecimalFormat formatting. I need to format double with values. I am using this pattern `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");` How to get the expected not actual?

```
Input    Expected      Actual

0.1 ->    0.01  ->     0.10
1.1 ->    01.01 ->     10.10
0.10 ->   00.10
10.1 ->   10.01 ->     10.10
10.10 -   10.10
```

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make sense. 0.1 **is** 0.10, not 0.01 as that would be a factor 10 smaller than 0.1.

Comment: Yes I see it can be done this way I will close the question

Comment: Any suggest how I can be done different way

Comment: If your values aren't actually single numbers, but two numbers separated by a period, you can't store them as a single `double`. Maybe you could store them as two `int`s, or in a string.

Comment: I will go with hard-coded formation, adding 0 to the string value if length is less than 2. Is that you have in mind